# Custom UIButton class with animation swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

Is it possible to create a **UIButton** class with an **onclick animation** which gets **automatically invoked** everytime the user **touches** the button?

```
import UIKit

class AnimatedButton: UIButton {

@objc private func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)

    // animation ...

    }
}
```

So I dont want to create an action in a ViewController in which button.buttonclicked() must be invoked. This should happen automatically everytime I use this class.

Is there any possibility to do something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like below, just replace the event which ever you are interested in.

```
class AnimatedButton: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AnimatedButton.buttonClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc private func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
        // animation ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below code when you tap on button it will call animate method and perform animation. When you want to perform animation on button just assign `AnimatedButton` class as Custom Class of UIButton :

```
class AnimatedButton: UIButton {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(animate), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func animate() {

        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks both solutions are working! Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer.. have a nice day